# Convert Id to value from a list from apex

Tags: visualforce

In one of my requirements I am populating a table with values from an apex controller. The values are being populated with the help of a list. The first column contains a link and when clicked an alert has to pop up wit the message and who the record is assigned to.

In the table assigned to value is displayed correctly. But when i use the same list to get the assigned to value to display in the alert only the id is displayed.

Can anyone tell me how to change the id to Name?

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!View.listOfRequestView}" var="RequestQ" rows="20" onRowClick="clickElem(this);" >
    <apex:column headerValue="WR #" >
       <apex:commandLink action="{!DetailPage}" onclick="return confirm - {!RequestQ[View.listOfFields[1]]}');" 
            <apex:param assignTo="{!RequestId}" name="IdPass" value="{!RequestQ.Id}"/>               
        </apex:commandLink>                  
    </apex:column>    
    <apex:column value="{!RequestQ[View.listOfFields[0]]}"  rendered="{!View.listOfColumnFlag[0]}" headerValue="{!View.listOfFieldLabel[0]}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!RequestQ[View.listOfFields[1]]}"  rendered="{!View.listOfColumnFlag[1]}" headerValue="{!View.listOfFieldLabel[1]}" />
</apex:pageblockTable>
```

Comment: Share your **VF page** and **controller** .

Comment: Share your controller as well.

Comment: Is the VF page working? You are using `View.listOfRequestView` as the collection for the table and `Request` to represent individual item/record in that collection. But you are not really using that variable in any place? Plz share your controller as well, it will save both of us time.

Comment: I think there are some flaws in your logic, kindly read this [article](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm) and associated pageblocktable exaple by googling.

Comment: the part of VF is working fine and the table are also loaded with the values.

Comment: If you cant share the controller, which is quite strange and irritating to be honest, then would you like to tell what is `RequestQ`? What is it holding? **P.S.**  but let me tell you, without proper information it would be very tough for us to help **you**.

Comment: The RequestQ is a method for which i am passing the field name of the Assigned To to get the name. For example when i try to pop an alert with only View.listOfFields[0] value i get the field name Asigned_To__c

Answer (score 0):

If the Assigned To is a lookup field to User on an sObject then in your SOQL query please use one more field name **Assigned_To__r.Name** and use it in the VF page.
Eg:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!listOfRecords} var="a">
<tr>
<td>{!a.Assigned_To__r.Name}</td>
.
.
</tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: i tried using the .name after the  {!RequestQ[View.listOfFields[1]]} expression, but did not work.